# Jquery form validation custom success message placement

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate, validation

in my form validation, error messages are placed in error box. But success messages are also appearing on that same box. i want to appear success messages next to my formfields like `error.appendTo( element.parent().next() );`
My current syntax is like;

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    var validator = $("#testform").validate({
        rules: {
            Field1: "required",
            Field2: "required",
            Field3: "required",
            Field4: "required",
        },
        messages: {
            Field1: "Specify Field1",
            Field2: "Specify Field2",
            Field3: "Specify Field3",
            Field4: "Specify Field4",
        },
        errorPlacement: function(error, element) {
                error.appendTo( element.parent().next() );
        },
        success: function(label) {
            label.html("OK").addClass("checked");
        }
    });
});
</script>
<form id="testform" name="testform" method="post" action="test.php">
<table>
<tr>
<td>Field1</td>
<td>
<input id="Field1" name="Field1" type="text"></td>
<td class="status"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Field2</td>
<td>
<input id="Field2" name="Field2" type="text"></td>
<td class="status"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Field3</td>
<td>
<input id="Field3" name="Field3" type="text"></td>
<td class="status"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Field4</td>
<td>
<input id="Field4" name="Field4" type="text"></td>
<td class="status"></td>
</tr>
</table>
</form>
```

and the style;

```
#testform label.error {
  background:url("unchecked.png") no-repeat 0px 0px;
  padding-left: 16px;
  padding-bottom: 2px;
  color: #CC0000;
}

#testform label.checked {
  background:url("checked.png") no-repeat 0px 0px;
  padding-left: 16px;
  padding-bottom: 2px;
  color: #008000;
}
```

What are the changes I have to make in my syntax??

I am using bassistance.de "Remember The Milk" as template. You can have a look [here.](http://jquery.bassistance.de/validate/demo/milk/)

Thanks in advance.. `:)`

blasteralfred

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can check the element's class to see if you're about to place an error message or a success message:

```
errorPlacement: function(error, element) {
    var container;
    if (element.hasClass("valid")) {
        container = element.parent().next();
    } else {
        container = $("#errorbox");
    }
    error.appendTo(container);
},
```

Comment: i think, errorPlacement triggers only errors, n the success messages wont b displayed in this logic...

Comment: @blasteralfred, it not clear from the source code. `showLabel()` appears to also be called on success. Did you try it? :)